# Rotating vector versus dot product

Tags: vectors, rotations

Suppose that I have a vector

$$
v = [v_0, v_1, v_2]^T
$$

which I want to project to

$$
n = [n_0, n_1, n_2]^T
$$

I did this with dot product of $v$ and $n$. As an alternative way, I wanted to rotate coordinate system and express $v$ in new coordinate system. I rotated coordinate system such that x axis is parallel to $n$ (or $x^{\prime}$ in figure). In new coordinate system, I expected component of $v$ in $n$ or $x^{\prime}$ axis to be equal to $v \cdot n$ in old coordinate system. I did $Rv$ with rotation matrix

$$
R =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta \cos \phi && \cos \theta \sin \phi && \sin \theta\\
-\sin \phi && \cos \phi && 0\\
-\sin \theta \cos \phi && -\sin \theta \sin \phi && \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where, $\theta$ and $\phi$ are obtained with

$$
\theta = \text{atan2} \left(\frac{n_1}{n_0}\right)\\
\phi = \text{atan2} \left(\frac{n_2}{\lvert n_0 \rvert}\right)
$$

Then I wanted to try an example. $v=[111.6, 14.701, 0]^T$, $n=[0.349026, 0.919137, -0.182667]^T$. The results I get from two methods are different (app. 52 vs 47). Clearly, I am misunderstanding something. May you spot the mistake please.

[image]

Comment: Did you take into account that $n$ is not quite a unit vector? I agree that the result of the dot product should stay the same after the rotation.

Comment: The numbers are provided are truncated. Edited to provide numbers with more precision.

Comment: Are you sure you got the rotation matrix correct? The first entry seems to be wrong: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5Bcos%28b%29%2C0%2Csin%28b%29%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B-sin%28b%29%2C0%2Ccos%28b%29%5D%5D*%5B%5Bcos%28a%29%2C+sin%28a%29%2C+0%5D%2C%5B-sin%28a%29%2C+cos%28a%29%2C+0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D)

Comment: That is a typo. In calculations the matrix was as the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the definition of $\phi$ which should be

$$
\phi = \sin^{-1} \left(n_2\right)
$$